# What are the differences between the Region 1 and Region 2 Releases of Revolver?

Tags: alternate-version, revolver

While reading the Wikipedia entry on the [2005 Film Revolver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolver_%282005_film%29#Home_media) I noticed it mentioned that

> Region 2 is the original 2005 theatrical release, while Region 1 is
>   the 2007 reedited version, created by Ritchie in order to simplify
>   and/or clarify some plot points after criticism that the film was too
>   hard to follow.

Can anyone explain or provide insight to what was changed between these two releases past what is [explained here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0365686/alternateversions)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This fantastic post over at IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0365686/board/flat/101790221?p=1) explains the differences in a lot of detail (given its length, I've chosen to just link to it rather than copy and paste it in its entirety).

**Edit**

A summary of some differences (note, the link above is far more comprehensive and descriptive). This is intended for all people who have seen the US version and are wondering how the UK version differs:

- Around 22 minutes in (after the Horowitz scene), there is an extra
  scene where Jake explains in the car to Avi and Zach his history with
  Macha.
- Around 1 hour in (after the scene in which the guy chasing Jake accidentally shoots himself), instead of the restaurant shoot-out scene, Jack goes to Paramount City to talk to Avi and Zach. The restaurant shoot-out scene follows this.
- During the Driving Range scene, there are a few extra comments inserted.
- Around the 1 hour, 16 minute mark (after Driving Range scene and Jake giving money to charity), instead of Mache scene where we start to hear his thoughts, the actual structure of the film is changed. Due to the complicated nature of what happens next, I will quote from the above article:

> We see the Machiavelli quote, then we have the scene where Jake is
>   standing in Macha's bedroom, admitting his inferiority to Macha (the
>   climax of the US version). This's plays out just like the US version
>   does. Instead of the US epilogue (where Jake and Avi play chess and
>   talk about Jake's enlightenment), after the "Fear me" scene it cuts
>   right into the "crucifixion" of Lord John's man and the scene where we
>   can start to hear Macha's thoughts. Originally, this marks the natural
>   transition of Mr. Gold's thoughts from Jake (where he is now
>   powerless) to Macha who has just been humiliated by Jake and deep in
>   fear of Mr Gold (So it now makes more sense why we now can hear
>   Macha's thoughts). Instead of the torture montage, Macha brags of
>   Jake's groveling the night before and that he "knows who's boss"
>   (conveniently forgetting to mention the "fear me" scene). Once Paul
>   tells him Jake was behind everything, Macha has a very brief flash of
>   the "fear me" scenes played back in his head (yelling instead of
>   whispering the words) instead of the "they don't fear me" monologue
>   the US version has. The UK version omits the "Sam Gold will kill me"
>   internal monologue and replaces it with one of the whispering/crying
>   "fear me" scenes.
>
> In the UK version, instead of letting the Sorter shooting spree scene
>   play out like seen in the US version, we get an over the phone
>   retelling of the event by the surviving flunky Lou to Macha. He says
>   he got tired of waiting at the car, went inside, saw Paul getting
>   carried away with the little girl, and "from out of nowhere, Sorter
>   shot him" (the dialog we hear in the US version is not in the UK
>   version thanks to the voice over of Lou). Macha is in disbelief. "Then
>   he turned the gun on the 2 bodyguards, both gone in a blink of an
>   eye." The rest of the scene plays out the same in both versions. At
>   the end of Sorter's killing spree when he is wiping his glasses, Lou
>   is the one who kills Sorter by shooting him in the back of the head.
>   Lou says he was the only one left. Macha asks "where's the girl?"
>   before the scene cuts to the exterior of Macha's casino.

- The next scene (which is Jake’s final meeting with Macha) is different as well.
- When Macha tells the clerk to bring Jake up, this is where the US
  epilogue is (where they talk about Jake’s new enlightenment). This is
  played out with added content and much more detail, to give the
  viewer a better understanding of what is (meant) to be happening.

Comment: Is there at least *some* way to summarize the linked post?

Comment: Lol. Posted it while at work, so I'll do it next time I take a wee break.

Comment: The IMDB link no longer works.